# Go to new URL at end of PHP Script

Tags: php, url

I'm trying to concatenate the current url with a variable, then push to that new URL at the end of the script. So far, I've got

```
 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

 $url2 = $file;

 $url3 = $url . $url2;
```

How do I push the user to $url3. I can't use header, I believe it's because I'm creating an html file in the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `header()`, you just need to make sure that you don't have any `echo` running before your call to `header()`, and that you don't have any extra spaces or lines at the beginning of a PHP script (before the first `<?php`. I bet the error you see is "Headers already sent".

```
header("Location: " . $url3);
```

Or you can echo a JS redirect at the end of your script. Assuming you are running this in a browser.

Comment: +1 Maybe show how to use header, or redirect (pardon the pun) to the documentation. It would be header('Location: url');

Comment: LOL. It looks like he already tried because he knows he can't use it. But thanks. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: I have echos running before it. The change in url is supposed to happen after everything else.

Comment: "The change in url" ... What do you mean? You want the user to be redirected to this page? If so, he won't even see whatever is echoed by the page.

Comment: The echos are just creating a new file. Should the header function be before everything happens?

Comment: What do you mean by "the echo are creating a new file"? The header function is going to be interpreted by the browser as "don't show the current HTML, take the user directly to the new URL specified in the header"

Comment: I don't even think the browser "reads" the body if the header tells it to go someplace else.

Answer (score 0):

If you already sent some output to the client, you want' be able to do that unless you will print a javascript.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript> window.location = \''.$url3.'\';</script>';
```

Although it is not a good approach, probably this script will came out after  closing tag. To avoid it try to buffer your output.

At the beginning of your php code add `ob_start()`

Then at the end try: `ob_end_flush()`

Then you will be able to send header.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps client-side redirect could resolve issue?

HTML redirect with Refresh meta tag:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Refresh_Meta_tag_and_HTTP_refresh_header

or JS redirect
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#JavaScript_redirects

Answer (score 0):

**Add this to the end of your script:**

```
echo <<< EOF
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">location.href = '$url3';</script>
EOF;
```